# Google Cloud: @endpoints.api, 'module' object has no attribute 'api'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

While trying to `appcfg.py update myProject`, my endpoints failed to update. Here is part of the trace:

```
09:36 PM Failed to update Endpoints configuration.  The app returned an error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate with it.
09:36 PM See the deployment troubleshooting documentation for more information: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/test_deploy#troubleshooting_a_deployment_failure
09:36 PM Ignoring Endpoints failure and proceeding with update.
```

I tried to check the logs at `http://localhost:8080/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs`, but terminal produces the following error:

```
@endpoints.api(name='EventsAPI', version='v1')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'api'
INFO     2016-03-18 02:01:37,742 module.py:787] default: "GET /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Here is my code:

```
import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote

package = 'Events'

@endpoints.api(name='EventsAPI', version='v1')
class EventsAPI(remote.Service):
    # insert lots of endpoint methods

APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([EventsAPI])
```

I am following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api). Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the endpoints' name. The name `EventsAPI` is invalid; changing it to `eventsapi` fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, as outlined in the [endpoint definitions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#defining_the_api_endpointsapi).

> The name value: Must begin with lowercase.